# Low poly normals when baking with Cycles

Tags: workflow, normals, normal-map

Blender novice here. I'm trying to make some models to use in the Unity3D engine.

I modeled a high poly tube and the low poly counterpart. Now I'd like to bake the normal map from the HP to the LP in order to make it look better. **Unfortunately the normal map is horrible, it seems that I somehow tried to bake from the lowpoly to the lowpoly.**

I followed this process:

1. Make the high poly
2. Make the low poly
3. Unwrap the low poly
4. Switch to Cycles renderer and assign a 1024x1024 image
5. Switch to **Normals** under **Bake**
6. Bake
7. ..
8. no profit?

This is my high poly and perfectly smooth tube and its counterpart, the low poly and perfectly jagged tube:

[image: High poly and low poly]

This is the result from the bake with "Selected to active":

[image: With normal map]

I may have been missing something during the process. What could be?

Comment: Welcome to the site! One of things to check is whether shading was set to *Smooth* for lowpoly. Other than that, were objects placed in the same place ?

Comment: To me, there will be no result in this bake anyway, as the HP is smooth, so you will not obtain a significant normal map. But in the principle, as @MrZak said, the two object need to be at the same place (overlap)

Comment: watch out the order in witch you select your two objects for baking, first high poly, then low poly. 
This is what is meant by selected to active so that I guess you could bake small other objects as part of your normal map (like stones on the ground) because every object you select is "selected" but the last one in case you noticed has a slightly different selection color and it means 'active'. very usefull

Comment: @MrZak yes, the two objects are in the same place. It turned out that I missed the _Smooth_ option! Now everything is nice. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure everything is smooth shaded. Then see to it that all normals are facing in the right direction. Or you can simply go to *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and normals will align to the face direction. If this does not help you, check your UV and make sure there are no overlapping UVs.

Answer (score -1):

you need to apply smooth shading to the low poly object first then
 bake it again